# Shipping quote on product page Magento

Tags: php, magento, ip

I'm trying to display shipping cost on product page with following code:

```
<?php
            if($_product->isSaleable())
            {
            $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote');
            $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCountryId('GB');
            $quote->addProduct($_product);
            $quote->getShippingAddress()->collectTotals();
            $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
            $quote->getShippingAddress()->collectShippingRates();
            $rates = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getShippingRatesCollection();

            $minPrice = PHP_INT_MAX;
            foreach ($rates as $rate) {
            $minPrice = min($minPrice, $rate->getPrice());
            }
            if ($minPrice == 0) {
                echo ('This item qualifies for FREE shipping');
            }
            elseif ($minPrice < PHP_INT_MAX) {
                echo ('Shipping to UK from £' . money_format('%i', $rate->getPrice()) . "\n");
            }
            }
            ?>
```

How can the system auto detect user ip? Instead of setting country id.

Comment: There are modules you can add, here is a free one written by one of the mods on the Magento stack which I've used a few times and is good -> https://github.com/tim-bezhashvyly/Sandfox_GeoIP

Comment: I have GeoIP installed, how to add it to the code above?

Comment: What do you mean you 'have GeoIP' installed?  The module I linked to?  Having the GeoIP tables is one thing, having methods you can access to use them in relation to Magento country codes is another. Look at the example given in the Github page for Tim's GeoIP module, depending on which module you are using your methods and therefore code are going to be different.